# How to integrate payumoney in windows phone 8.1 c# application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, payu, payumoney

I am working with windows phone 8.1[RT] c# application . I found this [documentation](https://www.payumoney.com/developer-doc.html)  , but they don't have integration in windows phone 8.1 c#[RT] application integration. can anyone have Idea about how to integrate in c# application ?

Thank you .

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/integrate-payumoney-in-Asp-Net/). Maybe you can get some idea from this.

Comment: Yes , I have go through it , but it was written for asp.net application . I need for c#[RT] application.

Comment: Final solution is , I am go through with webView

Comment: is its working after using webview in windows phone

Comment: yes, working perfect